# can we bind table layout with Sqlite database table?

Tags: android

I have one problem in my application. the problem is that can i bind table layout with Sqlite database table? and  one another is can i bind a grid view with Sqlite  database table?

I am retrieved the data from Sqlite database table and bind into a spinner view but the data was not editable.

Actually in my application data retrieved from Sqlite database table and bind with grid view or table layout and all data are editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Table Layout is not meant to be used for that even though the name play tricks. So the answer is no, you can't bind a table layout with a db table.